# using lastIndexOf to append anchors to containers with matching anchors

Tags: jquery

I was trying to wrap this up on my own but ran into one little snag. This is a follow up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966036/append-anchor-to-a-parent-that-contains-anchor-with-same-href-attribute). Basically, I need to remove the "index.html" from the end of the links from the 3 containers with class .list and .combination then add them to the appropriate containers. I can't get my head wrapped around how to make everything work together. I get a successful alert for the url variable but can't get it to work beyond that. Appending works perfectly though.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {

        $('ul.list li a, ul.combination li a').each(function(){
            var url = $(this).attr('href');             
            var n = url.lastIndexOf('/');               
            url.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
        });


        $('ul.list.combination li').each(function() {
            var element = $('.list li a[href="' + $(this).find('a').attr('href')
     + '"]');

                if (element.siblings('ul').length  == 0) {
                    element.after('<ul />');
                }

                element.next('ul').append($(this));
            });
        });
 </script>
</head>

<body>

 <ul class="list">
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.html">My Site</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com/index.html">Google</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com/index.html">Yahoo</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com/index.html">CNN</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.espn.com/index.html">ESPN</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="combination">
<li><a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.html">My Site</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.google.comindex.html">Google again</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="combination">
<li><a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.html">My Site Too</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.comindex.html">Yahoo Redux</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Here's the expected output:

```
 <ul class="list">
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.com">My Site</a>
  <ul><li><a href="http://www.mysite.com">My Site</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.mysite.com">My Site Too</a></li></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
  <ul><li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google again</a></li></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
  <ul><li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Yahoo Redux</a></li></ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com">CNN</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.espn.com">ESPN</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="combination">
 </ul>

 <ul class="combination">
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, one href is not  /index.html btw

```
$(function(){

            $('#lists li a').each(function(i, val){
                 $(this).attr('href', function(i, href){
                        var n = href.lastIndexOf('/');               
                                        var subString = href.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : s.length);
                                         return subString;
                 });

                 if($(this).parents('ul').hasClass('combination'))
                 {
                    var li = $(this).parent();
                    $('.list').append(li);
                 }
            });

        });


$('ul.list li a, ul.combination li a').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href'),             
            n = url.lastIndexOf('/'),               
            subString = url.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : url.length);

        $(this).attr('href', subString);

    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duK7x/10/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Almost there, the only part I should have been more specific about is that I actually need to remove anything after the last "/". So index.html could be mypage.cfm. That's why I was trying lastIndexOf. Sorry about that(newbies - geez).

Comment: Thanks for your patience. This one seemed to have broken it again. I thought it may have been the s.length since s wasn't defined anywhere but changing it to href or $(this).length still didn't do it.

Comment: Can u be more precisely, what seems to be the problem with my version on Fiddle. On your own code part u forgot to change the current href into the substring. I've added that part to my code block.

Comment: I didn't close a function! Works perfectly now. Thanks very much!